# Pick unique sub-objects from list of objects and transform them with Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

With the following data structure...

```
const branches = [
  { id: '1', brand: { id: 'A' }},
  { id: '2', brand: { id: 'B' }},
  { id: '3', brand: { id: 'A' }}
]
```

I want to pick unique brands... that's easy enough.

```
const pickBrands = RM.pipe(
  RM.map(RM.prop('brand')),
  RM.uniqBy(RM.prop('id'))
)
```

But ultimately, I need to transform a whole thing like this...

```
const brands = [
  { id: 'A', branches: ['1', '3'] },
  { id: 'B', branches: ['2'] },
]
```

I am kinda confused how could I approach that considering that after the first map, I am losing information about a branch.

**Final solution:**
https://runkit.com/fredyc/5d2e1bf1df8aec001aff7f64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help too:

```js
const group = R.pipe(
  R.groupBy(R.path(['brand', 'id'])),
  R.values,
  R.map(
    R.applySpec({ 
      id: R.path([0, 'brand', 'id']),
      branches: R.pluck('id'),
    }),
  ),
);

const branches = [
  { id: '1', brand: { id: 'A' }},
  { id: '2', brand: { id: 'B' }},
  { id: '3', brand: { id: 'A' }}
];

console.log('group', group(branches));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort, looks very similar to the accepted solution. I actually had a mistake in the expected outcome (edited question), branches prop should have been direct array, not an object.

Comment: I actually change my mind and accept this answer. Readability for once, but also because it's more understandable for me to add other properties to applySpec. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `R.groupBy` with `R.path` to group by `brand.id`, and then use `R.toPairs` and `R.map` with `R.zipObject` to generate the new object from the groups.

**Example (annotated by @ScottSauyet)**:

```js
const { pipe, groupBy, path, map, pluck, toPairs, zipObj } = R

const fn = pipe(
  groupBy(path(['brand', 'id'])), //=> {"A": [{brand: {id: "A"}, id: "1"}, {brand: {id: "A"}, id: "3"}], B: [{brand: {id: "B"}, id: "2"}]}
  map(pluck('id')),               //=> {A: ["1", "3"], B: ["2"]}
  toPairs,                        //=> [["A", ["1", "3"]], ["B", ["2"]]]
  map(zipObj(['id', 'brand']) )  //=> [{id: "A", brand: ["1", "3"]}, {id: "B", brand: ["2"]}]
)

const branches = [
  { id: '1', brand: { id: 'A' } },
  { id: '2', brand: { id: 'B' } },
  { id: '3', brand: { id: 'A' } }
]

const result = fn(branches)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

**Note:** My original solution used `R.applySpec({ id: head, branches: last })`, but it seems that I'm the only one to find it more readable.

Comment: Awesome, I was hoping to see an answer like. Not that I fully understand it, but thanks, it works!

Comment: Perhaps a slight improvement would be `map(zipObj(['id', 'branches']))`?

Comment: That was the original direction, and it's a good option, but somehow applySpec looked more readable to me.

Comment: I wrote my own version, came to see if there were answers that already looked like it, and it was exactly this one, with @customcommander's suggestion.  Great minds and all!  :-)

Comment: @OriDrori, I have a [suggested edit](https://runkit.com/crosseye/so-57059575) with comments to demonstrate how each step is processed.  It uses `zipObj` instead of `applySpec`, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Sorry, I have decided to change the accepted answer because I find it more readable. Using `head` and `last` seems confusing enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain old JS to achieve your outcome, use reduce with findIndex to check if the id already exists, if it does, push the id to the existing object, otherwise, push the new object:

```js
const branches = [
  { id: '1', brand: { id: 'A' }},
  { id: '2', brand: { id: 'B' }},
  { id: '3', brand: { id: 'A' }}
]

console.log(branches.reduce((a, {id, brand}) => {
  const i = a.findIndex(o => o.id === brand.id)
  i + 1 ? a[i].branches.id.push(id) : a.push({id: brand.id, branches: { id: [id] }})
  return a
}, []))
```

Comment: Using i + 1 to form 0 as falsy value when findIndex returns -1 is really neat!

Comment: @assoron It is, it works nice when the returned index is 0, because 0 is a valid index too :)

Comment: As much as neat it sounds, it's hard to explain it when someone sees in that code in my opinion. Without that comment from @assoron, I would be confused why + 1.

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but this is really hard to read in overall. These are not katas to compete for the shortest code :) I am writing code for humans, not machines.

Comment: Besides the more unique approach with  `i + 1` I don't see why this got downvoted. It's a clean approach. It tries to find whether any object in the accumulator already has the current id. If yes extend that object else create it.

Comment: I haven't downvoted. It surely is clever, but kinda messy.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a `Map` for collecting brands.

```js
const
    branches = [{ id: '1', brand: { id: 'A' } }, { id: '2', brand: { id: 'B' } }, { id: '3', brand: { id: 'A' } }],
    brands = Array.from(
        branches.reduce((m, { id: branche, brand: { id } }) =>
            m.set(id, [...(m.get(id) || []), branche]), new Map),
        ([id, branches]) => ({ id, branches: { id: branches }})
    );

console.log(brands);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I should have been probably more clear that I am looking for a functional approach. Appreciate the effort, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [`values`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#values) and [`reduceBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduceBy).

First let's define an empty template for brands:

```
const brandTmpl =
  { id: null,
    branches: [] };
```

Then let's define a function that returns the brand id for a given `branch`:

```
const brandId = path(['brand', 'id']);

brandId({ id: '1', brand: { id: 'A' }});
//=> 'A'
```

Then given a `brand` and a `branch`, let's define a function that "adds" a branch to a brand:

```
const brand = (brd, bch) => (
  { id: brandId(bch),
    branches: append(bch.id, brd.branches) });

brand(brandTmpl, { id: '1', brand: { id: 'A' }});
//=> {id: 'A', branches: ['1']}
```

Now let's use all of that to merge branches by brand:

```
const brands = reduceBy(brand, brandTmpl, brandId);

brands([
  { id: '1', brand: { id: 'A' }},
  { id: '2', brand: { id: 'B' }},
  { id: '3', brand: { id: 'A' }}]);

//=> { A: { id: "A", branches: ["1", "3"]},
//=>   B: { id: "B", branches: ["2"]} }
```

Finally we can simply extract the values:

```js
const branches = [
  { id: '1', brand: { id: 'A' }},
  { id: '2', brand: { id: 'B' }},
  { id: '3', brand: { id: 'A' }} ];

const brandId = path(['brand', 'id']);

const brandTmpl =
  { id: null,
    branches: [] };

const brand = (brd, bch) => (
  { id: brandId(bch),
    branches: append(bch.id, brd.branches) });

const brands = reduceBy(brand, brandTmpl, brandId);
const pickBrands = compose(values, brands);

console.log(

  pickBrands(branches)

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {path, append, reduceBy, compose, values} = R;</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer, although I still like the approach from accepted answer more.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const branches = [
  { id: '1', brand: { id: 'A' }},
  { id: '2', brand: { id: 'B' }},
  { id: '3', brand: { id: 'A' }}
]  

const groupBy = (branches) => branches.reduce((acc, ele)=>( (acc[ele.brand.id] = acc[ele.brand.id] || []).push(ele), acc),{})
   
const reformat = ([k, v]) =>({id: k, branches: {id:v.map(({id})=>id)}}) 

const result = Object.entries(groupBy(branches)).map(ele => reformat(ele))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: So I suppose there is no purely functional approach that would be also readable? I can surely manage a similar code like that, but I am kinda trying to learn Ramda more.